# What is the equivalent of End (VB6/VBA) in order to end in C# for Windows applications?

Tags: c#, vb6

What is the equivalent of `End` (VB6/VBA) in order to end an application using C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "End"? You mean the "With/End With" construct?

Comment: End what? A method? The application? what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The marked answer is not correct.  Application.Exit() is a graceful shutdown, it can be blocked by a form's FormClosing event handler setting e.Cancel = true.  The exact equivalent to the VB End statement is Environment.Exit(0);

Answer (score 4):

To terminate Windows Forms application use:

```
Application.Exit();
```

To terminate a console application you must return the main function.

Comment: I would believe that `Environment.Exit` is closer to the VB.NET `End` statement.